# Sentence improvement question: which is the right answer?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, exam-questions

By the time tomorrow, I (will reach) my home.

1. will be reaching
2. shall have reached
3. can reach
4. no improvement

What would be the appropriate answer, i think it should be 2

Comment: We don't say *by the time tomorrow*. If you mean *exactly 24 hours from now*, that would be *By **this** time tomorrow [I will have reached my home].* Note that there's also *By the time I reach my home tomorrow, it will be dark,* where it's not idiomatic to have adverbial ***tomorrow*** directly after ***time***. But apart from that "error" in your first 4 words, all your alternatives are syntactically valid (though they mostly mean slightly different things).

Comment: I've noticed that community members have had to edit every one of your questions to fix serious formatting issues and simple punctuation and capitalization mistakes. You can and should do better. You can see the changes that have been made on a post by clicking the "edited..." link. There is advice on [meta] for [writing a good title](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2630/9161) and a [formatting sandbox](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2923/9161) that you can use to practice.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, "By THIS time tomorrow..."

"will be reaching our destination" is something you might hear a pilot say on an aircraft. Very formal.

"shall have reached" is archaic. No one uses "shall" anymore.

"can reach" can means the ability or possibility for something to be done or to happen. It does not mean that something was or will be done or happen. However, if you were away from home, talking to someone, who wasn't going with you, about going home, you might say you "can reach home by this time tomorrow."

People sometimes do say something about "reaching" a destination. But they don't usually use "reach" when their destination is home. Home is, by definition, a point of origin. Origin is the opposite of destination. You might reach up to a high shelf to get something. You don't reach down from the shelf after you got it.

Answer (score 0):

By this time tomorrow, I'll be home.

That's the usage most native english speakers would use. Other variations just come across as too formal, without the context the sentence is being used in.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.